# Centos Your PHP MySQL library version 1.5.73 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.39

Tags: centos, mysql, php

I have recently updated my PHP version to 5.4 and my mysql version to 5.5

```
    [root@**** ~]# php -v
PHP 5.4.31 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2014 07:41:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

When i enter my PHPMyAdmin i get the following warning:

```
Centos Your PHP MySQL library version 1.5.73 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.39.
```

What can i do to get rid of this warning?

As you can see my `mysql` version is correct:

```
    [root@***** ~]# mysql -u root -p -e 'SELECT VERSION();'
Enter password:
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.39    |
+-----------+
```

**Update**

i have tried the following:

```
    [root@*****~]# yum update php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * extras: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * updates: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * webtatic: nl.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Update Process
Package(s) php-mysql available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for Update
```

Comment: you cant update a package which one is not installed on your system. first you need to  install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install php-mysql if it not there

```
yum install php-mysql -y
```

It looks like you're using a 3rd-party repo to provide PHP 5.4, and the package php54w-common from that repo is conflicting with php-mysql (which is presumably coming from epel), which is expecting the default CentOS version of php-common.

Your 3rd-party PHP provider might provide their own version of php-mysql (try `yum info php54w-mysql` and see if that gives you anything). If this won't work than you have to find another package of PHP mysql compatible with php54w-common .Revert to the CentOS-supported PHP 5.3 instead of using PHP 5.4 .Build your own PHP 5.4 mysql package from your 3rd-party provider

Comment: I get the following when i try:  Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64

Comment: Did you upgraded the php version?

Comment: remove the old version first and than install php again with php-mysql option

Comment: Also tell centos version you are using.

Comment: i am kind of a noob to Centos how do i remove the old versions ? and install the new one with php-mysql option enabled?

Answer (score 0):

this warning means that your **php-mysql** module is an older version. you need to update it.

For example in RHEL/Fedora

```
yum update php-mysql
```

Then, do not forget to restary web server.

Comment: check my update please :)

Comment: php-mysql is not installed on your box. try to install it. you should learn how to use yum package manager to install,remove and update a package. for example , yum install php-mysql